# SQL Exception on immediate reconnect

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql, tcp, merge-replication

I have a winform app that uses LinqToSql as it's DAL.  There is a Central SQL DB and each laptop has a local SQLExpress DB.  A seperate module, using Merge Replication, keeps the two in sync.  When connection is lost to the central DB it 'fails over' to the local.  This works great.

However, when I regain conection to the central db, if the time period has not been real long, I get the following exception -->

`A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)`

I have read through numerous posts here on **SO** relating to this and even this [msdn article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/04/16/a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-when-sending-the-request-to-the-server-provider-tcp-provider-error-0-an-existing-connection-was-forcibly-closed-by-the-remote-host.aspx) that outlines and explains, in great detail, what is going wrong yet, through all of this, I have still not found or read a solution.

I am wondering how others have dealt with this.  I find it hard to believe that I am treading new ground here.  Is there a way to remove my old connections on reconnect?

I am losing hair over this so any insight is appreciated.

**EDIT**

Also of note, I am quite positive that all my `Data Contexts` are wrapped in a `using` and I do not have any 'long-term' contexts.

Comment: Just a suggestion:  try disabling connection pooling.  When you "close" an ado.net connection it's not actually closed, it's returned to the connection pool so it can later be reused.

Comment: Sure thing, is that a per connection thing or a Server thing?  I am sure I'll find it though.

Comment: It's a setting that can be added to the connection string itself, just add: Pooling=false.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Why don't you change your comments to an answer and I will mark you as that was the ticket.  I was being dense but you helped me out.  Thanks

Comment: @Refreacted Paladin: Thanks, that was sort of an off the cuff thought, so I put it as a comment rather than an answer.  I hate putting down answers that I haven't really thought through, but thank you for asking for it and accepting it as an answer. =)

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: No problem, thanks for taking the time to answer even the simple(obvious) questions!  Not everyone does.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off Connection Pooling using the "Pooling=false" connection string attribute seems to have solved the problem.